# health monitoring to eventlog setting source

Tags: asp.net, health-monitoring

I want to setup health monitoring in my asp.net app (using .net 4.5).

In production we will log the health events to a separate database (along with other operational type data).

In development though I'd like to setup to use the event log so there isnt a need to setup the other database when developing.

I have got logging to the event log working however I don't know how I can filter out the event log events only for the ones for my application.

Looking at them an event looks like this

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          29/07/2012 8:50:46 PM
Event ID:      1305
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      scorpion
Description:
Event code: 1004 
Event message: Application compilation finished. 
Event time: 29/07/2012 8:50:46 PM 
Event time (UTC): 29/07/2012 10:50:46 AM 
Event ID: 41f9c898cda14f7685f5c448f13f806a 
Event sequence: 10 
Event occurrence: 4 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/5/ROOT-1-129880325799889790 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: c:\users\pyro\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication3\MvcApplication3\ 
    Machine name: SCORPION 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 556 
    Process name: iisexpress.exe 
    Account name: scorpion\pyro 

Custom event details: 

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">1305</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-07-29T10:50:46.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>6775</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>scorpion</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>1004</Data>
    <Data>Application compilation finished.</Data>
    <Data>29/07/2012 8:50:46 PM</Data>
    <Data>29/07/2012 10:50:46 AM</Data>
    <Data>41f9c898cda14f7685f5c448f13f806a</Data>
    <Data>10</Data>
    <Data>4</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/5/ROOT-1-129880325799889790</Data>
    <Data>Full</Data>
    <Data>/</Data>
    <Data>c:\users\pyro\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication3\MvcApplication3\</Data>
    <Data>SCORPION</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>556</Data>
    <Data>iisexpress.exe</Data>
    <Data>scorpion\pyro</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

The only thing that might be useful is the application domain but it doesn't look like that there is a way to access that through an [eventlogentry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.aspx) short of doing some kind of nasty parsing.

Is there something I'm missing here and I could actually set something in the log that would make it easier to filter out ones just for my app, I could look for the asp.net string but that doesn't guarantee its only going to get things directly related to my app.

If it isn't possible to do this without having to rewrite the provider, is there a better provider to use for a throw away kind of development scenario that doesn't require much setup.